# ¿Cómo sacar estadísticas de ejecución en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Ayer llegué al capítulo de Índices del libro en el que estudio. Venían esta imagen, en la que muestran el tiempo de ejecución de unas consultas, y luego una imagen similar pero con el time consumption menor una vez introducidos los índices:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es esa, ¿cómo sacar eso por pantalla? Es que no lo dice. He buscado en internet y usando `set autotrace on explain;` saca estadísticas pero no son las del libro. ¿Alguien sabe el comando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de como quiera obtener el tiempo de ejecución, por lo general para una query yo ejecuto un `explain plan for`.

Por ejemplo:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
      SELECT sysdate from dual;

 SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo quiere hacer dentro de un procedimiento puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
PROCEDURE tu_procedimiento AS
--Variables
v_start_time NUMBER;
         v_elapsed_time NUMBER;
BEGIN
 v_start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
 --Ejecución de procesos
 v_elapsed_time := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME - v_start_time;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TIEMPO DE EJECUCION: ' || v_elapsed_time);
END;
```